# First data in the listview should be checked by default

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I have a requirement that when I am entering zip code and pressing the enter key on the emulator/tablet i am getting list of operator names in the ListView. Inside Listview I am using  checkedtextview to populate the data using my custom array adapter.

The listview should be checked at a time one operator name only. Whenever the data is populated to the listview the first operator name should be checked by default.

Is there any way to find out the solution.

I am using the custom array adapter like this

```
private class OperatorListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private HashMap<Integer, Boolean> selectOperatorStatusMap = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();

    public OperatorListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<String> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);

        selectOperatorStatusMap.put(0, true);
        for (int i = 1; i < objects.size(); i++) {
        selectOperatorStatusMap.put(i, false);
        }
    }

    public void toggleChecked(int position) {
        if (selectOperatorStatusMap.get(position)) {
            selectOperatorStatusMap.put(position, false);
        } else {
            selectOperatorStatusMap.put(position, true);
        }

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void unChecked(int position) {
        for (int i = 0; i < selectOperatorStatusMap.size(); i++) {
            if(i!=position){
                checkedTextView.setChecked(false);
                checkedTextView.setCheckMarkDrawable(R.drawable.uncheck);
            }
        }
    }

    public List<Integer> getCheckedItemPositions() {
        List<Integer> checkedItemPositions = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < selectOperatorStatusMap.size(); i++) {
            if (selectOperatorStatusMap.get(i)) {
                (checkedItemPositions).add(i);
            }
        }

        return checkedItemPositions;
    }

    public List<String> getCheckedItems() {
        List<String> checkedItems = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < selectOperatorStatusMap.size(); i++) {
            if (selectOperatorStatusMap.get(i)) {
                (checkedItems).add(operatorList.get(i));
            }
        }

        return checkedItems;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.provider_list, parent, false);
        }

        checkedTextView = (CheckedTextView) row.findViewById(R.id.list_text);
        checkedTextView.setText(operatorList.get(0));
        Log.i(TAG, "OperatorListAdapter:"+operatorList.get(0));
        Boolean checked = selectOperatorStatusMap.get(position);

        if (checked != null) {
            checkedTextView.setChecked(true);
        }

        return row;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. in `getView` instead of

```
if (checked != null) {
   checkedTextView.setChecked(true);
}
```

Use:

```
if (position == 0) {
    checkedTextView.setChecked(true);
}
else{
    checkedTextView.setChecked(false)
}
```

Comment: in checkedtextview i using selector for check and uncheck.so with this the selector is not functioning